# nasm function called from C ends up segfaulting

Tags: c++, nasm

I have to find min max values in array using only one conditional jump directive.

After compiling and linking the two files below I get a `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`, but I don't understand why that is.

**Question**: What is causing the *segmentation fault*?

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
extern "C" void minmax(int n, int * tab, int * max, int * min);

int main(){
   const int rozmiar = 100000;
   const int liczba_powtorzen = 10000; 

   int tab[rozmiar] = {1, 3, 3, -65, 3, 123, 4, 32, 342, 22, 11, 32, 44, 12, 324, 43};
   tab[rozmiar-1] = -1000;

   int min, max;

   min = 99999;
   max = -99999;


   clock_t start, stop;
   start = clock();

   for(int i=0; i<liczba_powtorzen; i++){
      minmax(rozmiar, tab, &max, &min);
   }

   printf("min = %d    max = %d\n", min, max);

   stop = clock();
   printf("\n time = %f ( %d cykli)", (stop - start)*1.0/CLOCKS_PER_SEC, (stop - start));

   return 0;
}
```

**minmax.asm**

```
global minmax               ; required for linker and NASM

section .text              ; start of the "CODE segment"

minmax:
    push ebp           
    mov ebp, esp        ; set up the EBP
    push ecx            ; save used registers
    push esi


    mov ecx, [ebp+8]    ; array length n
    mov esi, [ebp+12]   ; array address
    mov eax, [ebp+16]   ;max
    mov edi, [ebp+20]   ; min


lp:     add eax, [esi]  ; fetch an array element
        cmp eax, [esi]
        jl max          ; max<[esi] ->update max
        cmp edi, [esi]
        jg min          ; min>[esi] ->update min
        add esi, 4      ; move to another element
        loop lp         ; loop over all elements

max: 
    mov eax, esi
    ret

min: 
    mov edi, esi
    ret

    pop esi             ; restore used registers
    pop ecx
    pop ebp
    ret                 ; return to caller
```

Comment: "I was able to write sth like this" : What is sth?

Comment: IS segfault happening inside the minmax function? You should be able to run the program in gdb and figure out the stack trace at the time of the segfault and also which instruction causes segfault.

Comment: @Spundun `Sth` is function that is not working correctly and also do not follow the requirements of only one conditional jump.

Comment: Related: How about initializing `max` and `min` before sending them into the abyss of your asm function? Right now its UB.

Comment: yes this is good idea I will change code.

Comment: I'm still confused... is sth short for "something"? Also you should be able to be more specific about OS. Also even after @WhozCraig 's advice if you get segfault then you should run the program in gdb to pinpoint the instruction where the segfault occurs

Comment: In fact since core is dumped, you should be able to open the core file in gdb and examine the backtrace

Comment: @Rafik991 see my edited answer for a detailed description of why it segfaults.

Comment: @Rafik991 - 'using only one conditional jump directive' - could you clarify this part of the problem statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you're exactly trying to do, but the assembler function is written poor.

Try this:

```
   push ebp           
   mov ebp, esp        ; set up the EBP
   push ecx            ; save used registers
   push esi

   mov ecx, [ebp+8]    ; array length n
   mov esi, [ebp+12]   ; array address

   mov eax, 0x80000000
   mov edi,[ebp+16]
   mov [edi], eax
   mov eax, 0x7fffffff
   mov edi,[ebp+20]
   mov [edi], eax

lp:
   mov edi,[ebp+16]
   lodsd
   cmp [edi], eax
   jg short _min_test
   mov [edi], eax

_min_test:
   mov edi,[ebp+20]
   cmp [edi], eax
   jl short _loop
   mov [edi], eax
_loop:
   loop lp

   pop esi             ; restore used registers
   pop ecx
   pop ebp
   ret                 ; return to caller
```

Answer (score 3):

**Long story, short**:

You need to restore the stack before using  `ret`.

Your *asm*  implementation is faulty on many levels, but the reason for your *segmentation fault* is poor understanding of how `ret` works.

---

**Invalid use of `ret`**

`ret` does not bring you back to the last *jump*, it reads the value that is at the top of the stack, and returns to that address.

After you jump to either `min:` or `max:`, you call `ret`, where you should be jumping back to your loop.

This means that it will try to *return* back to the address at the top of the stack, which certainly isn't a valid address; you modified it upon entering the function.

```
push ebp           
mov ebp, esp        ; set up the EBP
push ecx            ; save used registers
push esi            ; note, this is where `ret` will try to go
```